# Как локализовать (перевести) колонки таблицы Ext.grid.Panel?

Tags: extjs

Я пытаюсь сделать перевод колонок следующим образом:

Ext.define("Element.locale.ru.office.view.element.workstationList.WorkstationList", {
    override: "Ews.office.view.element.workstationList.WorkstationList",
    title: "Список рабочих мест",
    columns: [{
        dataIndex: "PARAMS",
        text: "Параметры"
    }]
});

В надежде что по dataIndex сенча автоматом подменит только text (аналогичный механизм задействован при наследовании полей в моделях).

Но увы, здесь ничего подобного нет и происходит то, что и должно происходить. Параметр columns перезаписывается новым, в итоге все настройки колонок теряются.

Песочница https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1q4p

Как правильно локализовать колонки таблицы?

Answer (score 0):

В свое время, я не заморачивался locale или сторонними разработками (плагинами, бандлами), доступными в общем доступе. В DOM при загрузке страницы я формировал элемент вида

```
<script id="Localizator" ...>
var Localize {
    'firstname' : 'Имя',
    'lastname' : 'Фамилия'
    ...
};
</script>
```

Написал метод для получения этого объекта и его значений, ну и использовал в формате

```
columns: [{
    header: Ext.app.Loc('firstname')
}]
```

Это прекрасно работало на ExtJS 3.2, насчет современных версий ExtJS пока ничего сказать не могу)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Скорее всего так и сделаю.